# Java CompletionStage not propagating exception to exceptionally

Tags: asynchronous, exception, java-8, completion-stage

I am using async programming in one of my project. In one of the method where the return type is CompletionStage, for testing I am simulating an exception throw which does not get caught in the exceptionally(). Below are some Test code i created based on the use case.

```
public class TestMain {
  
  TestService service = new TestService();
  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    TestMain t = new TestMain();
    System.out.println("STARTED: THREAD " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    t.execute("test").toCompletableFuture().join();
    System.out.println("DONE: THREAD " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
  }
  
  public CompletionStage<Void> execute(String s) {
    System.out.println("EXECUTE: THREAD " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
      System.out.println("EXECUTE-ASYNC STARTED: THREAD " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      process(s);}).exceptionally(ex->{
        System.out.println("EXECUTE-ASYNC EXCEPTIONAL: THREAD " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.err.println("EXECUTE-ASYNC EXCEPTIONAL-EXCEPTION " + ex.toString());
        if (ex.getCause()!=null)
          System.err.println("EXECUTE-ASYNC EXCEPTIONAL-EXCEPTION CAUSE " + ex.getCause().toString());
        throw ex instanceof CompletionException ? (CompletionException) ex : new CompletionException(ex);
      });
  }
  
  private CompletionStage<Void> process(String s) {
    System.out.println("EXECUTE-PROCESS: THREAD " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
//    throw new RuntimeException();
    return service.service(s);
  }

}

public class TestService {
  
  public CompletionStage<Void> service(String s) {
    System.out.println("SERVICE: THREAD " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
//    throw new RuntimeException();
    return preProcess(s).thenCompose(v -> {
      System.out.println("SERVICE-PRE PROCESS -> COMPOSE: THREAD " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      return process(s);
    });
  }
  
  private CompletionStage<Void> preProcess(String s) {
    System.out.println("SERVICE-PRE PROCESS: THREAD " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
//    throw new RuntimeException();
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
  }

  private CompletionStage<Void> process(String s) {
    System.out.println("SERVICE-PROCESS: THREAD " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    throw new RuntimeException();
//    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
  }
  
}
```

When i run the code given above the output shows that the exceptionally() in TestMain.execute() is not called.

Actual Output (when exception thrown from TestService.process()):

```
STARTED: THREAD main
EXECUTE: THREAD main
EXECUTE-ASYNC STARTED: THREAD ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
EXECUTE-PROCESS: THREAD ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
SERVICE: THREAD ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
SERVICE-PRE PROCESS: THREAD ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
SERVICE-PRE PROCESS -> COMPOSE: THREAD ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
SERVICE-PROCESS: THREAD ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
DONE: THREAD main
```

However if I throw the exception at any other place, which are marked by the commented code, the exceptionally() is called. Below is an example of one such instance.

Actual Output (when exception thrown from TestService.preProcess()):
Was expecting above output to be similar to this.

```
STARTED: THREAD main
EXECUTE: THREAD main
EXECUTE-ASYNC STARTED: THREAD ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
EXECUTE-PROCESS: THREAD ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
SERVICE: THREAD ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
SERVICE-PRE PROCESS: THREAD ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
EXECUTE-ASYNC EXCEPTIONAL: THREAD main
EXECUTE-ASYNC EXCEPTIONAL-EXCEPTION java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException
EXECUTE-ASYNC EXCEPTIONAL-EXCEPTION CAUSE java.lang.RuntimeException
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1643)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1632)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1703)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:172)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at in.TestService.preProcess(TestService.java:19)
    at in.TestService.service(TestService.java:11)
    at in.TestMain.process(TestMain.java:34)
    at in.TestMain.lambda$0(TestMain.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1640)
    ... 5 more
```

Can somebody help out as to why this is happening? I need the exception thrown to be caught in the TestMain.execute().exceptionally() always to implement a retry logic that I want to use here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: removed the duplicate output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking a method which returns a `CompletionStage` but ignoring the returned value:

```java
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
  System.out.println("EXECUTE-ASYNC STARTED: THREAD "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
  process(s); // return value ignored
})
```

The stage created by `CompletableFuture.runAsync(…)` would be completed exceptionally if the function/`Runnable` threw an exception. Which is what happens when you place `throw new RuntimeException();` inside the `process` method. But in the other scenario it doesn’t throw an exception but returns a failed stage which is ignored by the caller.

You could change the code to

```java
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
  System.out.println("EXECUTE-ASYNC STARTED: THREAD "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
  process(s).toCompletableFuture().join();
})
```

to not ignore the returned stage or, preferably, use the pattern you’ve already used at another place:

```java
CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null).thenComposeAsync(v -> {
  System.out.println("EXECUTE-ASYNC STARTED: THREAD "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
  return process(s);
})
```

Comment: Exceptionally doc says  
exceptionally(Function<Throwable,? extends T> fn)
**Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when this CompletableFuture completes, with the result of the given function of the exception triggering this CompletableFuture's completion when it completes exceptionally; otherwise, if this CompletableFuture completes normally, then the returned CompletableFuture also completes normally with the same value.**
So the exceptionally on runAsync should be completed when the exceptionally is invoked right?

Comment: by the way, your solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If **exceptionally** is not used on every level and an exception is thrown from a nested **CompletionStage** (for example thenAccept), then the exception will not be propagated up the chain to the next exceptionally handler.

This is because the **thenAccept** method returns a CompletionStage, which is a special case of CompletionStage that does not carry a result. When a CompletionStage completes exceptionally, it does not return a new CompletionStage that represents the exceptional result. Instead, the exception is silently propagated up the chain and lost.